# Should VHDL and other hardware description languages go on Stack Overflow or Electrical Engineering?

Tags: discussion, migration, site-recommendation

Today I ran into a question on the "new questions page" about handling some VHDL code, after answering it, I decided to look at other, similar, questions and noticed a large propensity of them getting little to no traffic/answers/votes etc.  Many of these low traffic questions that I saw were good questions; where as, and maybe I'm stretching too far, but if the question was language agnostic or more high level or even in another language it would have higher visibility.

Now this is where I want to find out what the policy should be (or maybe already is), should there be some line in the sand that is drawn; where in, the questions should be moved to the electrical engineering site, where it is more likely to get a better response and more visibility within a community that more routinely uses these languages and paradigms that are attributed to hardware based programming.  I know, from my experience with lurking on both sites routinely, that I see faster responses with more visibility from the EE.SE site (with my responses routinely being "sniped" because someone has more experience than I on the topic and can get the same response I would give out faster and more eloquently) on these topics than on the main SO site.

My main concern with this is that if questions about things like VHDL and Verilog stay at this low end visibility on SO, and they're new to the SE family of sites, they probably won't know and won't get redirected correctly if there isn't a decent policy on this.  And as such will be discouraged from asking questions of that nature on here in the future.  Furthermore, with low visibility there's the likelihood that someone answering won't necessarily be incentivised to put in the effort to answer the questions either since there's no guarantee that their answer will reward them based on the quality, because again, I saw many quality answers to these same types of question with only a single vote, or maybe two, and little to no traffic.

I understand that these languages and the design therein isn't a mainstream language topic or process, and maybe that's where I'm getting hung up, but if that's the case they should be diverted to a community that already handles questions in this arena, and a migration of question from SO to EE.SE should be considered.

[I feel like this is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548981/vhdl-simulates-fine-but-doesnt-act-the-same-in-hardware?rq=1), the first comment shows a redirect towards EE.SE, but, the problem with this is, if he re-asks the question over there, it's duplicating information across multiple SE sites which is a no-no, so instead it sits, with a moderately good answer (accepted but only partially accurate in its statements) and a near zero likelihood of someone giving something better with a more thorough explanation, since there's really no incentive to do so (near no traffic == near no votes/publicity == near no impetus to make a "better" answer known).

Comment: I am not familiar topical focus of EE.SE, but it seems to me that if the question is on topic for either site, the OP should be free to choose one or the other. Experienced posters such as yourself can help guide him/her via comments to close the original question and post it in a place that is likely to receive more traffic.

Comment: So, the result should be that we're making some sort of judgment call as to whether it's a more appropriate EE.SE or SO question based on experience, and then using our kindly guiding hands push the person in the direction that seems best?

Comment: That seems like the best approach to me. The experienced users of the site are in the best position to make such judgments, and the new user benefits from the guidance by posting on the site that is likely to provide the best exposure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and maybe this is another question for meta entirely, do we have statistics of people who's first and only question is migrated, whether they stick around or better yet, start pro-actively using the site that they were migrated to?

Comment: None that I have seen, but it seems likely that this information can be dredged out of the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/). I agree that another question is warranted. Someone may already have a query for that.